# How long does it take to apply changes on sync framework?

Tags: windows-services, microsoft-sync-framework

So, I've been syncing databases from azure to local SQL. I've already synced azure database in 45 minutes, which is not that bad at all, considering I have 200+ tables and countless rows on my database.

Problem is when I'm syncing to local, it's taking a lot of time. I've been practically sitting on this for three hours and still, the `sqlServerProv.Apply()` functionality hasn't finished yet.

Any ideas on how long this takes?

Here's my sample code, or a part of it.

```
SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlServerProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlServerConn, myScope);


// Apply the scope provisioning.
 sqlServerProv.Apply();
```

Also, it's a windows service so I can't really debug other than creating a log file if any error throws, so far, none has triggered any errors yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that code is provisioning...that's not synchronizing... it's just creating the objects needed by Sync Framework (tables, triggers, stored procedures, etc...)

when provisioning, Sync Fx populates the tracking tables...so if you have a table in your sync scope that has 10M rows, it will insert 10M rows in the tracking tables.

how big is your database?

Comment: I have a table that has 1m+ rows on it, and that's just one table. I have 200+ tables some range from 2k-700k so it's kinda big. Is it possible that it takes this long?

Comment: hard to tell without knowing your server and database specifics... you can fire up SQL Profiler to check on commands going to your database.

Comment: You're answers were helpful. Now I am able to track whether there was an error or something to the code. Thanks!

Comment: I have  a similar problem, but, not when I do provision. The problem is that my data is to big. The process in the parent take a lot of time. When I try to do an EndSession in the child, the father is working yet. How I can receive a mark, or something, that tell me that the father finished all the work? Summary, the father take his time!, but the child never know if the father finish or not, ever, SyncFramework do a lock of the table and do not allow any query in the father! Help! Please! Thanks!